# Number of each row.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my database 3 records and i want that they looks like:
if I using for (each)

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
```

1. record1
2. record2
3. record3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want `each_with_index`. something like:

```
<% @records.each_with_index do |record, i| %>
   <%= (i+1) %>. <%= record.foo %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use each_with_index:

```
<% @records.each_with_index do |record, i| %>

  #your code

<% end %>
```

Comment: d'oh, beaten by 43 seconds! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in an ol, that way the numbering is dynamic:

```
<ol> 
   <% @records.each do |record| %>
     <li><%= record %></li>  
   <% end %>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at each_with_index:

```
<% @records.each_with_index do |record, index| %>
```